# An estimator for a Cumulative distribution function

Tags: statistics

The salaries in a company distribute in a cumulative distribution function,

[image]

λ is a constant.

1. Am I correct to understand that η represents the minimum salary that is taken into account, and that the probability for every single salary is in relation to it? i.e the bigger the minimum salary, the smaller the probability becomes for every salary in the function.
2. How can I calculate an estimator for η by moments and with n values?

Thank you

Comment: [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters).. Minimum observed value is MLE of $\eta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post I am going to assume that $\eta$ and $\lambda$ are both positive constants.

You are correct in saying that the smallest possible observable salary is  $\eta$, but larger values of $\eta$ don't necessarily yield smaller probabilities. For example, taking $\eta=6$ and $\lambda=9$ gives $$P(\eta+1<Y<\eta+2)=\int_{\eta+1}^{\eta+2}f_{Y}(y)dy\approx 0.174$$ Increasing $\eta$ to $7$ while keeping $\lambda$ fixed at $9$ yields a slightly larger probability of $0.196$. You will notice upon inspection of the pdf $f_{Y}=F_{Y}^{\prime}$ that salaries are skewed to the right are thus are concentrated around the minimum salary of $\eta$.

For part $(b)$, consider a simple random sample $Y_1=y_1, \ldots ,Y_n=y_n$ of $n$ independent salaries in the company. The likelihood function is $$\mathcal{L}(\eta)=f_{Y}(y_1)\times \dots \times f_{Y}(y_n)=\frac{\lambda^n \eta^{n\lambda}}{(y_1 \times \dots \times y_n)^{\lambda+1}}$$ whenever $0<\eta \leq \min\Big\{y_1,\ldots ,y_n\Big\}$ and $0$ elsewhere. Since $\mathcal{L}$ is increasing in $\eta$ we see that the value of $\eta$ which maxmimizes $\mathcal{L}$ is $\hat{\eta}=\min\Big\{y_1,\ldots ,y_n\Big\}$. This is your MLE and, in my opinion, a natural estimator for the minimum salary $\eta$.

Comment: Would you say that the MLE is biased in this case? I'm thinking that because Y min is a value out of n values the probability for it wouldn't be 1, and therefor the mean of Y min is not equal to η. Would love to hear your thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Here's how you can figure out if $\hat{\eta}$ is biased estimator for $\eta$.

Define $\hat{\eta}=\min\big\{Y_1, \ldots ,Y_n\big\}$ where $Y_1,\ldots ,Y_n \sim  f_{Y}$ are iid. The pdf of $\hat{\eta}$ is well$-$known to be $$f_{\hat{\eta}}(y)=nf_{Y}(y)\big[1-F_{Y}(y)\big]^{n-1}=\frac{n \lambda \eta^{\lambda n}}{y^{\lambda n +1}}$$ whenever $y \geq \eta$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then when $n>\frac{1}{\lambda}$ $$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\eta})=\int_{\eta}^{\infty}yf_{\hat{\eta}}(y)dy=\frac{n \lambda \eta}{\lambda n -1} \neq \eta$$ so $\hat{\eta}$ is a biased estimator for $\eta$.